# how to get fresh clean docker image of my broken image in Ubuntu

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Im fighting with my broken installation of Nextcloud in container. My problem is when i tried to use `docker system prune -a` and after that `docker-compose up -d` from my yml, same broken image was loaded...
I dont understand that... I am something missing? Or some files are still in filesystem?
I need to get rid of this broken instalation and make new fresh clean container with new installation on Nextcloud.
Of course recover of Ubuntu working, but is pretty stupid solution.
Thanks

Comment: What image are you pulling with `docker-compose`? Check the `.yml` file. Are you pulling an official container, or one you created yourself?

Comment: I am pulling an official nextcloud:lastest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might still have a volume existing with Nextcloud data or even the volume with the Nextcloud database as `docker system prune -a` doesn't remove volumes.

You can list and delete the volumes with the commands :

```
docker volume ls
docker volume rm volume
```

Or even this one to also prune the volumes :

```
docker system prune --volumes
```

---

`docker-compose` is also often used to creates the volumes in folders in the current directory.
You can check if you have new folders like `app`/`bdd`/`data`

Comment: Thanks for your advice, this was one half of the problem. I thought `prune -a` remove also volumes. Secomd half of the problem was remaining `app` and `proxy` files in my directory where is also `docker-compose.yml` file. After this two things done, my problem was solved